# Display the content and title of a specific page on Homepage

Tags: wordpress, codex

I want the title and content of a specific page to show in my Homepage and footer area.

It will be something like this.

> This is the Title of the page
>
> This is the content of the page, etc....blahh blah..
>
> ```
>                            readmore...
> ```

I know that there is no excerpt in the page post. But i want to limit the characters of the content that will show in the footer area.

Can you give me a code/link/tutorial that will show me how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is excerpt avaIlable in the page posts. Just set it in the **Screen Options**.

About the code try this one which I use on my projects.

It will show excerpt of those pages, which have custom field named **showOnHomePage** and the value of this field determines the order in the list.

```
 $pages=get_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'showOnHomePage', 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC'));

  foreach( $pages as $page ) 
  {
    echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_permalink( $page->ID ).'" >'.get_the_title( $page->ID ).'</a></h2>';
    echo $page->post_excerpt;
    echo '<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">Read More</a>';
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any excerpt in the Screen Options of my Page Post.

Comment: Ok i got a excerpt now, by adding add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' ); in my functions.php